# difference in differences estimation using regression

Tags: multiple-regression

How do I differentiate between independent variables and control variable in difference in differences estimation using regression model.

Comment: What is the difference in your mind? These are usually synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the model you're using, independent variables and control variables are the same. They're synonyms. If what you meant was what the difference between *dependent* variables and control variables, the dependent variable is the one whose behavior you want to study. In order to do that, you ask how this dependent variable changes as a result of changes in your independent/control variables.